# creating UML or class diagram manually from existing project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, documentation, class-diagram, tool-uml

Is there anyway to build manually a class or UML diagram from some part of existing code in Visual Studio Professional? Assume there are plenty of project and classes. Can i manually select some of the classes (with only some of its base/derived classes and member functions) I am interested in, and they are automatically transferred to boxes with arrows and so on...?

The trivial and slow solution is to draw some boxes and corresponding arrows and then write the name of classes or member functions into boxes (With some drawing programs like Dia). However, can it be done maybe using a more efficient way with any plugin or extension?

Because, my final aim is to make my own documentation (visually) from the code i am working at. The code is big and I want to develope my own documentation only on some selective parts during the next years...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [install the Class Designer component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-designer/how-to-add-class-diagrams-to-projects?view=vs-2022).

In addition, [UML Designers have been removed](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/uml-designers-have-been-removed-layer-designer-now-supports-live-architectural-analysis/).